# Display content based on the role of the user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a menu with sections that are visible only to some users. I have the role user, role admin1 and role admin2 in my database.
For example, how do I make Category 2 visible to ROLE_ADMIN1 only?

Knowing that my users can have multiple roles, or all roles at once. As you see below, each user has the ROLE_USER role, but the only difference is that ROLE_USER can only be ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN1, or ROLE_ADMIN2, or both at the same time.

```
{
         "name": "Jack",
         "fname": "Daniel",
         "roles": [
           "ROLE_USER"
         ]
       }


       {
         "name": "Laly",
         "fname": "Dom",
         "roles": [
           "ROLE_USER",
           "ROLE_ADMIN1"
         ]
       }


       {
         "name": "Admini",
         "fname": "Strator",
         "roles": [
           "ROLE_USER",
           "ROLE_ADMIN2"
         ]
       }<br><br>            {
         "name": "Admini",
         "fname": "Strator",
         "roles": [
           "ROLE_USER",
           "ROLE_ADMIN1",               
           "ROLE_ADMIN2" 
           ]
       }
```

my html :

```
<ion-item class="item-stable animsvdj" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
      <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-android-contacts' : 'ion-android-contacts'"></i>
      &nbsp; Category
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion menu-border" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.disponibilites" menu-close=""><i class="ion-ios-calendar-outline menu-icon"></i>   Category 1</ion-item>

    <!-- Part that should be visible only by admin -->
    <ion-item class="item-accordion menu-border" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.organiseVisite" menu-close=""><i class="ion-ios-time-outline menu-icon"></i>   Category 2</ion-item>
    <!-- Part that should be visible only by admin -->

    <ion-item class="item-accordion menu-border" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.trouverUnJeune" menu-close=""><i class="ion-ios-eye-outline menu-icon"></i>   Category 3</ion-item>
```

in my controller:

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $ionicHistory, AppService) {
            $scope.group = [];
            $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
              if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
                $scope.shownGroup = null;
              } else {
                $scope.shownGroup = group;
              }
            };
            $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
              return $scope.shownGroup === group;
            };

      })
```

Thank you all !

Comment: Where is the json coming from? I would return the available menu items from the backend and use angular's equivalent for-loop binding.

Comment: What is "isGroupShown"?  I do not see a function for that.

Comment: http://nadeemkhedr.com/how-to-do-authorization-and-role-based-permissions-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i think the best practices to handle this logic in backend level ,

so you send the token and the back end guys have to check the roll from the

token it self and return the data based on the permission that you have ,

also  to make sure your data is secured .

if you don't care about the mentioned you can do something like so and filter your data on client side

```
  $scope.adminData = []; 
  $scope.data = [{data:'some user data',roll:'user'},{data:'some admin data',roll:'admin'}]
        data.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr){
        if(currentValue.roll == "admin"){
        $scope.adminData.push(currentValue);
        }
        })
```

after this repeat the adminData array in your view if the logged in user has the admin permission

in this case i prefer to do the logic inside your component this is will

provide you a better for maintenance and cleaner view .